# Configure TFS server location in TFS powertools

Tags: tfs-power-tools

I'm trying to unshelve a shelveset to another branch using the tfpt utility included in TFS Powertools. However, since I installed the TFS power tools we have moved the TFS server to another server (with a different URL).

The problem is that when I am using TFS power tools it tries to access the old server which leads to an error saying

> Team Foundation Server  does not exists or is not
>   accessible at this time. Technichal information (for administrator):
>   The request failed with HTTP status 503: Service unavailable.

Does anyone know how do I tell tfpt to use the new server location instead? I thought that this would be solved by making a simple search on google but I was wrong :/

Answer (score 3):

Problem resolved! :) I've added the new server to my Visual Studio 2008 installation (in Team Explorer). I previously did this for my Visual Studio 2010 only. So now tfpt are using the new server location instead.

Comment: +1 - this worked for me (updated VS 2012 but forgot to update VS 2010). It appears that one also has to reboot for the shell integration to pick up on this.

Comment: Didn't work for me - changed the Server in all 3 versions of VS I have: 2008, 2010 and 2012... I'm using the 2010 Power Tools.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also.
I'm running 2013,2015, and 2017
I updated to a new tfs server in each of these but my shell extensions were not working.

I resolved the issue by restarting explorer.
just open up task manager and restart the process.
(for those people like me that don't like to have to reboot all the time)